# how to save file to telegram server?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I want to send a large video file using pytelegrambo but it only has a limit of 50mb

when I read the documentation https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#sending-files to send large files there it says
If the file is already stored somewhere on the Telegram servers, you don't need to reupload it: each file object has a file_id field, simply pass this file_id as a parameter instead of uploading. There are no limits for files sent this way.

so, how to save it on telegram server?

Comment: Send the file to the bot, it should receive the file_id in the corresponding event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to upload files more than the limits mentioned on API's [documentation](https://docs.telethon.dev/), you will have 2 options:

1. Use an MTPROTO API Client (for Python there is [Telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev/)):

   ```py
   await client.send_file(chat, zip_file, progress_callback=action.progress)
   # You're going to replace `chat`, `zip_file` and `action.progress` with your desired functions.
   ```
2. Use a [Local Bot API Server](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#using-a-local-bot-api-server):

   ```
    git clone --recursive https://github.com/tdlib/telegram-bot-api.git
    cd telegram-bot-api
    mkdir build
    cd build
    cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
    cmake --build . --target install
   ```

   Then you can run the server using:

   ```
    telegram-bot-api --api-id=API_ID --api-hash=API_HASH --local
   ```

   And have your BOT API send requests to or receive updates from `http://127.0.0.1:8081`.

   You can get your API_ID & API_HASH by signing in [here](https://my.telegram.org/apps) and filling out the API Development Tools form.

   Also don't forget to use `--local` when running the server, because without it you can't upload files more than the limits of a normal Bot.